# Problems with UICollectionView iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So Im having the strangest trouble with what I thought should be super easy. Here's my collectionView

[image]

So.. as you can see the right image is cut off. Now here's the weird part. Here's my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 164, 164)]; // 0 0 164 141
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    imageView.image = usersPhotos[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

And here's the **UICollectionView** in my storyboard file:

[image]
**NOTICE** that my collectionViewCell in storyboard file is 155 by 155 and my *imageView* is 164x164. I'm doing this because I just can't figure this out for some reason:

With my *imageView* set to 155x155(the same size as cell), we get something that looks like this:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong here? It's clear that I dont want that white spacing (as shown above) and I cannot expand my UICollectionViewCell anymore because 155 is the max width, for some reason on storyboard if you hit a width of 156 it makes the cell take up the entire column, **with no room left for a second column**, which is what I need.

How can I simply make this work? Any help is greatly appreciated, Im greatly lost as to why I am experiencing this behavior and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you implementing either delegate method collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath or collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex and returning a different size or insets? ... also another thing to consider, do you have any auto layout constraints set that might be affecting it?

Comment: I have neither delegate methods implemented. I do however have "Autoresize Subviews" check box **checked** for the UICollectionViewCell in Storyboard file.

Comment: On the left side of your storyboard expand your collection view, do you see a yellow object called "Collection View Flow Layout"? If so click on it, then in the right pane click on your size inspector and look at "Min Spacing". In my sample project it was set to 10 for cells and 10 for lines, set those to 0 then your cell max size should be able to be set to 160.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard expand your view controller and select "Collection View Flow Layout" like so:

[image]

Then in your size inspector find Min Spacing like so:

[image]

Change the "For Cells" spacing to 0. That will allow you to fit your cells in without any spacing between them, and increase your cell size to 160 max (for a screen width of 320).

This changes my storyboard layout from this to this with a cell size of 160w:

[image][image]

Then when I run the app all the cells are touching:

[image]

Comment: Had to change "For lines" to 0 as well, but this worked perfectly. Great! thanks for your bossed out answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your cell size is hardcoded in the storyboard, you have to make it dynamic, so that it changes depending on which device your app is running on.

You have to implement the UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate method, something like this:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width/2, collectionView.frame.size.width/2);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It's making the collectionView 1 column only.

Comment: You should also check your section insets, and minimumInterimSpacing. So your cell width+left inset+right inset+interim spacing should not be greater then collectionView's width.

Comment: I've checked the insets, there are none but I will try to print them anyway. No idea what minimumInterimSpacing is or where to find it.  I even just set all the insets to 0 with: `- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}`

Comment: take a look at this for more info on interim spacing and more: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/

Answer (score 0):

Your cells will need to resize based on the size of the device and the section insets and inter item spacing.

In storyboard, make sure Flow layout is selected in the Attributes Inspector on your Collection View.

Then, implement the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` and calculate with the section insets:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Get the flow layout properties
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)collectionViewLayout);

    // Calculate the usable width for the cell
    CGFloat usableWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width - flowLayout.sectionInset.left - flowLayout.sectionInset.right - flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing;

    // Return the proper size
    return CGSizeMake(usableWidth / 2, usableWidth / 2);

}
```